# Can I lose files from my SSD if some sector dies?

Tags: windows, ssd

I know that SSD disks have much shorter lifespan than HDDs, but I wonder, is it possible to lose files on this SSD disk once a sector on it gets corrupted? 
I plan to use more and more SSDs in the future, and I want to be 100% sure that I can rely on that.

Comment: It is my understanding that the longevity limit to SSDs is not about actual age but number of writes. Either way, if your file intersects a bad block, and the system was not able to extract an undamaged copy of the data when it reallocated that block, then yes, your file will be corrupt or lost.

Comment: " is it possible to lose files on this SSD disk once a sector on it gets corrupted?" - Just like any sector on any storage device, if the sector is not functional, then the data on it cannot be read.  In the case of a SSD and most flash devices, once the cell reaches its lifetime writes, you just can't write to it anymore.  Its not clear if your actually talking about a bad sector, or the lifetime of a given cell, which by the way represents more then a single sector on the disk.  You should edit your question so it is clear.

Comment: `Can I lose files` - **Yes.**  Make backups.  Ideally at least 3, with one offline/remote, and/one on a different type of media.

Comment: You need to distinguish between hard and soft failures.  A soft failure is simply bad data, not physical damage.  That has more to do with things external to the storage medium.  It can happen with any type of medium, and the ability to reconstruct the original contents is usually limited.  A hard failure is physical failure of the storage medium.  The contents may or may not be readable/recoverable.  An SSD tends to be be more recoverable than a HDD because the common failure mode is losing the ability to write to the block, but it can still be read, and the contents relocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern SSDs drives have a set of "spare" flash cells to replace defective ones and apply a dynamic sector mapping (round robin) in order to ensure an even cell wearing. 
In the past years the SSD technology and reliability has improved to the point that the MTBF is higher than the an HDD MTBF [See Storagereview Comparison](http://www.storagereview.com/ssd_vs_hdd)
In the end, as any electronic device it could fail, but I don't see modern SSDs as inherently insecure as the firsts generations ones.

Comment: so does that mean I can rely on files not get lost once a sector gets corrupted and dies?

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer - If the sector is corrupt, then the fragments of the files contained on that sector. also become corrupt.  What do you mean by "once a sector dies" exactly?

Comment: I mean getting corrupt

Comment: When a sector becomes corrupt you won't be able to recover the information stored there but, as I said in my answer, it's an unlikely event. Today's SSDs reliability is roughly the same than HDDs. When was the last time you saw a bad sector on a HDD?